# C#: Convert a generic function to a Func object

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following function:

```
private int GetEnumTypeUnderlyingId<T>()
        {
            return (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), Enum.GetName(typeof(T), _franchise.LogonDialog));
        }
```

I want to convert it to a `Func type`. I write something like:

```
Func<int> GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<T> = () => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), Enum.GetName(typeof(T), _franchise.LogonDialog));
```

But this does not work. I am not really comfortable when working with Func<>, Generics and lambda expressions so any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: It won't works that way since C# does not support Generic Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own delegate. Here is what you are looking for:

```
//Your function type
delegate int GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<T>();

//An instance of your function type
GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<int> myFunction = () => //some code to return an int ;
```

Also this works too.

```
//An instance of Func delegate
Func<int> GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc = () => //some code to return an int;
```

Comment: The lambda expression still depends on `T`. I'm not sure if using `GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<T>` instead of `GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<int>` would work.

Comment: The thing is by using `GetEnumTypeUnderlyingIdFunc<int>` you specialize the original generic method `GetEnumTypeUnderlyingId<T>`. It's now only valid for `int`.

Comment: @Drik Yes and that's what the question is asking for (as far as I understand).

Comment: Ok, I thought he wanted one single delegate to be used instead of the generic function, not make a delegare for each particular type.

Comment: Can You please having in mind the code i have posted, give example how can I get the int from any type of enum i pass for <T> ?

Comment: @Mdb What are you going to do? convert `Enum` to `int`? or convert an `Enum` instace to `int`? It is not clear.

Comment: convert an Enum instace to int

Comment: @Mdb simply do this: `int result = (int)enumInstace`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
public Func<int> GetTheFunc<T>(T val)
{
    Func<int> func = () => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T),Enum.GetName(typeof(T),val));
    return func;
}
```

Then

```
var func = GetTheFunc<_franchise>(_franchise.LoginDialog);

//Now you can use the func, pass it around or whatever..
var intValue = func();
```